# SSRS 2008 R2 Ranged Bar Chart (Gantt) multiple values per category

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, gantt-chart

I'm trying to produce a gantt style chart by using the SSRS 2008 R2 ranged bar chart. Gantt chart is for tracking task start and end dates, where task may be stopped and started with these intermissions recorded.

DataTable columns: TaskName, StartDate, EndDate

I can get the chart to display the first row for each TaskName on my chart but I have some instances where there are more than one table row per task with differing dates. i.e. I may start a task, do another task for a bit then step back to a task.

I followed this example to get to this stage: http://pnarayanaswamy.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/range-bar-chart-gantt-chart-using-ssrs.html

Is this request possible with this chart object, if not what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  It's actually in the link you refer to:

> To view all the sub task data series group in one line, you need to set this DrawSideBySide to False for all the sub task data series.